# convertir objet en imagenes

Tags: javascript

mi código es el siguiente:

```js
document.querySelector('.ranking').innerHTML += '<p style="color:rgba(105, 109, 115,  0.465);">Jefes de incursión Actualizados con éxito...</p>';
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pokemon-go-api/pokemon-go-api/gh-pages/api/raidboss.json';
request.open("GET", url);
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    const posts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    posts.currentList.lvl1.forEach(item => {
      document.getElementById("raid1").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
      <div class="ranking_item">
      <div class="ranking_img  ${item.types[0]}">
      
      <img src="${item.assets.image}">
      <img  src=${item.shiny ? "assets/img/icon/shiny_white.png" : "assets/img/icon/no-shiny-icon.png"} >
      <div class="poke_type">
      
      ${item.types.map(a => '<div><img src="'+ a.types +'"></div>')}
      
  </div>
      <div class="ranking_name">
          <span>${item.names.Spanish}</span>
          </div>
          
      </div>
      <div class="ranking_info">
      <div class="ranking_name" style="display: none;">
      
      </div>
      
      <span>PC Potenciado</span>
      <p>${item.cpRangeBoost[0]} - ${item.cpRangeBoost[1]}</p>
      <span>PC Normal</span>
      <p>${item.cpRange[0]} - ${item.cpRange[1]}</p>
      </div>`
        ); }    );
}
}
```

```html
<div class="ranking">
     <div  class="ranking_block" id="raid1">
    </div>
     </div>
```

me ayudarían con esto:
estoy recorriendo el objet:

```
     "types": [
               "Normal",
               "Flying" 
               ]
```

intento acceder usando un map, para mostrar ambos resultados:

```
    ${item.types.map(t => '<div><img src="'+ t.types +'"></div>')}
```

y estoy obteniendo como resultado:

```
          <div><img src="undefined"></div> , <div><img src="undefined"></div>
```

como podría hacer para obtener el nombre y convertirlo en imagen y evitar que salga la coma (,)

mi idea es extraer los nombres de los typos y mostrarlos dentro de un

```
         <div> <img src"www.link.es/type1"></div>
         <div> <img src"www.link.es/type2"></div>
```

mi json tiene algunos un Type y otros 2.
ayuda por favor

Comment: Buen día, hasta lo que entiendo es que quieres generar un link para cada elemento del arreglo de `types`, ejemplo: primer link es `www.link.es/Normal`, y el segundo `www.link.es/Flying`, es así o me equivoco?

Comment: exacto, tal cual: www.link.es/Normal.png que los obtenga automáticamente de mi json, las imágenes las guardaria en cualquier almacenamiento en de imágenes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te doy un ejemplo.

Tendrías que primero ingresar a los valores de la clave `types`, que en este caso es el array con los elementos que irán en el `src` de tus imágenes, así:

```
const types = obj.types; // aquí ya ingresé a los valores de "types".
```

Luego recién recorres con el `map()` a los valores ingresados, así:

```
const result = types.map(type => `<div>imagen: <img src="www.link.es/${type}"></div>`);
```

Ahora, recuerda que el `map()` devuelve un arreglo con lo recorrido (ahí el problema de las `,`). Entonces, deberíamos convertirlos en una cadena de texto para hacer un `innerHTML` al `div` donde queremos mostrar los resultados, para esto utilicé `join('')`:

```
document.getElementById("imagenes").innerHTML = result.join('');
```

Código completo (explicación en comentarios):

```js
let obj = {
  "types": [
    "Normal",
    "Flying"
  ]
}

// primero ingreso al valor de "types", que es un array => ["Normal", "Flying"].
const types = obj.types;

// mapeo sus valores y concateno cada valor con la cadena => <img src="www.link.es/${...}"></div>.
const result = types.map(type => `<div>imagen: <img src="www.link.es/${type}"></div>`);

console.log(result)

// Recuerda que map() devuelve un array, es por eso que se utilizó join() para devolver una cadena y no el array (por eso tenías las ",").
// Entonces, al ser ya una cadena, puedo hacer un innerHTML al div con el id "imagenes" sin problemas.
document.getElementById("imagenes").innerHTML = result.join('');
```

```html
<div id="imagenes"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias, Cris lo tengo ahora mas claro.. ya logre solucionar...